# Why am I getting NaN when I join two DataFrame that have no NaN in them (multilevel index)?

Tags: python, join, pandas, merge, dataframe

I have two data frames with multilevel index r1 and r2 such that

```
a1=['iso3_o', 'iso3_d', 'year', 'ExportFoodAndLiveAnimals']
a=np.array([['CAN', 'USA', '1995.0', '5918210.506'],
       ['CAN', 'USA', '1996.0', '6988508.727'],
       ['CAN', 'USA', '1997.0', '7792977.258'],
       ['CAN', 'USA', '1998.0', '8177456.631'],
       ['CAN', 'USA', '1999.0', '8773990.755'],
       ['CAN', 'USA', '2000.0', '9650783.071'],
       ['CAN', 'USA', '2001.0', '10800432.88'],
       ['CAN', 'USA', '2002.0', '11348837.38'],
       ['CAN', 'USA', '2003.0', '11313334.46'],
       ['CAN', 'USA', '2004.0', '12337588.35'],
       ['CAN', 'USA', '2005.0', '13227226.96'],
       ['CAN', 'USA', '2006.0', '14236699.34'],
       ['CAN', 'USA', '2007.0', '15638919.3'],
       ['CAN', 'USA', '2008.0', '17449901.08'],
       ['CAN', 'USA', '2009.0', '14813089.89'],
       ['CAN', 'USA', '2010.0', '16399733.82']])
r1 = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=a1)
r1
```

and r2 is defined as

```
a1=['iso3_o', 'iso3_d', 'year', 'contig']
a=np.array([['CAN', 'USA', 1995, 1],
       ['CAN', 'USA', 1996, 1],
       ['CAN', 'USA', 1997, 1],
       ['CAN', 'USA', 1998, 1],
       ['CAN', 'USA', 1999, 1],
       ['CAN', 'USA', 2000, 1],
       ['CAN', 'USA', 2001, 1],
       ['CAN', 'USA', 2002, 1],
       ['CAN', 'USA', 2003, 1],
       ['CAN', 'USA', 2004, 1],
       ['CAN', 'USA', 2005, 1],
       ['CAN', 'USA', 2006, 1],
       ['CAN', 'USA', 2007, 1],
       ['CAN', 'USA', 2008, 1],
       ['CAN', 'USA', 2009, 1],
       ['CAN', 'USA', 2010, 1]])
r2 = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=a1)
r2
```

Then I decided to join them on a multi index level of

Therefore, what I have done I reset the columns to index

```
 multi_r2 = r2.set_index(['iso3_o', 'iso3_d','year'])
    multi_r1 = r1.set_index(['iso3_o', 'iso3_d','year'])
    df = multi_r2.join(multi_r1)
```

the DataFrame df is giving me a NAN when I join them on 'iso3_o', 'iso3_d', 'year'

Why is this happening?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why are your year dtypes not in agreement? one is str and the other is int?

Comment: Besides, this should've worked I can reproduce your error, if you did `r2.combine_first(r1)` and then set the index then it should work, what is your pandas version as this looks like a bug to me, mine is 0.18.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How may I merge data in python without getting Nan of the non Nan elements as I join?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36317904/how-may-i-merge-data-in-python-without-getting-nan-of-the-non-nan-elements-as-i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `year` column in `r1` and `r2` is both `str`, but not the same, change it to int will work

```
r1['year'] = [int(float(i)) for i in r1['year']]
r2['year'] = [int(i) for i in r2['year']]
multi_r1 = r1.set_index(['iso3_o', 'iso3_d','year'])
multi_r2 = r2.set_index(['iso3_o', 'iso3_d','year'])
df = multi_r2.join(multi_r1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had seems simple but I think I would like to share it with you. Basically just as EdChum pointed out I have to change the data type of the years to do so I have gone through list of steps. Maybe there exist a much simpler way but I am not aware of it if you are please share.

## Extract the values and save them in a numpy array

```
import scipy
a=r1.values
C = scipy.delete(a, 2, 1)
```

## Create a numerical number to the year variable and concatenate it with the new array

```
n=np.array(range(1995,2011)).reshape(1,16)
C1=np.concatenate((C, n.T), axis=1)
C1
```

## Extract the columns of the previous array r1 and resample this array such that the year is at the very end

```
cols=list(r1)
cols
cols.insert(len(cols)-1, cols.pop(cols.index('year')))
cols
```

## Recreate the DataFrame r1 as

```
r1=pd.DataFrame(C1,columns= cols)
r1
```

## Then do the same steps I have done earlier

```
multi_r2 = r2.set_index(['iso3_o', 'iso3_d','year'])
multi_r1 = r1.set_index(['iso3_o', 'iso3_d','year'])
df = multi_r2.join(multi_r1)
```

This now works fine for me

Comment: You can actually do this in one line - just cast it to a float and then to an int. ```r1["year"] = r1.year.astype(float).astype(int)```